# React Native Linking: how to provide the custom project path?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm integrating React Native into the existing android app and a bit stuck with the third-party libraries linking phase:

It appears, that `react-native link <library-name>` uses the default android project path such as:

```
/Users/eljoy/Documents/Git/MyProject/android/src/main/res/values/strings.xml
```

but my actual project path looks as follow:

```
/Users/eljoy/Documents/Git/MyProject/android/myproject/src/main/res/values/strings.xml
```

I was able to provide the correct path for the main Android file adding the following code to the package.json:

```
"rnpm": {
   "android": {
     "mainFilePath": "opencalls/src/main/java/me/opencalls/App.java"
   }
 }
```

Is there a way to explicitly provide the correct path for the whole android project?
Is there also a way to prevent ios linking?